# How to reference C++ library with no class / namespace?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a 3rd party C++ .lib that I would like to use in a C# application.

My intent is to write a managed C++ wrapper .dll for the .lib, and then include that wrapper dll in my C# application, using a process roughly like [the one outlined at this link](http://tom-shelton.net/index.php/2008/12/11/creating-a-managed-wrapper-for-a-lib-file/).

The header file for the .lib does not indicate any class declaration or namespace, just method names:

```
int CheckNamedVariable(const char* _name);
int RegisterNamedVariable(const char* _name);
double GetNamedVariableValue(int _id);
double GetNamedVariableTypedValue(int _id, int _units);
void SetNamedVariableValue(int _id, double _value);
... (etc)
```

I checked the lib with DUMPBIN /exports to see if I could glean any additional information, and got the following:

```
File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  ?AircraftVarGet@@YANHHH@Z (double __cdecl AircraftVarGet(int,int,int))
                  ?CheckNamedVariable@@YAHPBD@Z (int __cdecl CheckNamedVariable(char const *))
                  ?DLLStart@@YGXXZ (void __stdcall DLLStart(void))
                  ?DLLStop@@YGXXZ (void __stdcall DLLStop(void))
                  ?GetAircraftVarEnum@@YAHPBD@Z (int __cdecl GetAircraftVarEnum(char const *))
                  ?GetModuleVar@@YANW4GAUGE_TOKEN@@@Z (double __cdecl GetModuleVar(enum GAUGE_TOKEN))
                  ?GetNameOfNamedVariable@@YAPBDH@Z (char const * __cdecl GetNameOfNamedVariable(int))
                  ?GetNamedVariableTypedValue@@YANHH@Z (double __cdecl GetNamedVariableTypedValue(int,int))
                  ?GetNamedVariableValue@@YANH@Z (double __cdecl GetNamedVariableValue(int))
                  ?GetUnitsEnum@@YAHPBD@Z (int __cdecl GetUnitsEnum(char const *))
                  ?IsPanelWindowVisibleIdent@@YAHI@Z (int __cdecl IsPanelWindowVisibleIdent(unsigned int))
                  ?Panels@@3PAUPANELS@@A (struct PANELS * Panels)
                  ?RegisterNamedVariable@@YAHPBD@Z (int __cdecl RegisterNamedVariable(char const *))
                  ?SendKeyEvent@@YAXII@Z (void __cdecl SendKeyEvent(unsigned int,unsigned int))
                  ?SetNamedVariableTypedValue@@YAXHNH@Z (void __cdecl SetNamedVariableTypedValue(int,double,int))
                  ?SetNamedVariableValue@@YAXHN@Z (void __cdecl SetNamedVariableValue(int,double))
                  _ImportTable
                  _Linkage

  Summary

          ED .debug$S
          14 .idata$2
          14 .idata$3
           4 .idata$4
           4 .idata$5
          1A .idata$6
```

In my managed wrapper project, I can point the Linker input to the .lib, but I'm not sure how to call the methods in the lib (the tutorial I linked to makes use of namespaces and classes). If it were a plain old DLL in a C#/VB project, I could view the object browser and get some idea of how to call the library.

But given my C++ ignorance, I'm in the dark. Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
I tried just creating methods with the same name as the methods listed in the header, e.g.:

```
int VariableExporter::IsPanelWindowVisibleIdent(unsigned int panel_id)
{
    return IsPanelWindowVisibleIdent(panel_id); 
}
```

This is not doing what I'd hope, it's just recursively calling itself (until it has a - wait for it - Stack Overflow).

Then I tried renaming the wrapper method like this:

```
int VariableExporter::IsPanelWindowVisibleIdent_New_Name(unsigned int panel_id)
{
    return IsPanelWindowVisibleIdent(panel_id); 
}
```

Now, although the C++ .DLL project and the C# project both compile, the C# project throws a FileNotFound exception when it tries to load that .DLL.

Comment: Use `extern "C"` for symbols exported to C# .... (or to C).

Comment: Please forgive the ignorance of what I'm asking but... wouldn't this belong in the source code for the .lib? I don't have access to that source... just the binary lib and the header file.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, to call global level function, you need to use the scope resolution operator `::`

```
int VariableExporter::IsPanelWindowVisibleIdent(unsigned int panel_id)
{
    return ::IsPanelWindowVisibleIdent(panel_id); 
}
```

There is no need (at least for this simple case), to rename your method.

Secondly, for DLL-not-found issue, check that DLL is present in the `bin` path of your C# application. Also, check that wrapper-DLL itself is loadable (use Dependency Walker). Ensure that bit-ness of wrapper DLL and C# application also matches. A 64-bit application cannot load 32-bit DLL (and vice versa).